# Representation of an integral with big $O$ terms

Tags: real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series, asymptotics

Let $\Theta\subset\mathbb{R}$ and consider the integral
$$
\int_\Theta f(t) \left| \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} g(x_n) t+ r_n(t) \right|dt,
$$
where:

$\bullet$ $n$ is an integer sequence, the sequence of real numbers $x_n$ converges to $x$ as $n \to \infty$;

$\bullet$ $g$ is a real-valued function which is continuous in a neighborhood of $x$;

$\bullet$ $f$ is a positive, continuous function and $\int_\Theta |t|f(t)=c<\infty$;

$\bullet$ for any fixed $t$, $r_n(t)=O(1/n)$ and $\int_\Theta f(t)|r_n(t)|dt=O(1/n)$.

Under the above assumptions, would it be correct to write:

$$
\int_\Theta f(t) \left| \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} g(x_n) t+ r_n(t) \right|dt= c \frac{|g(x_n)|}{\sqrt{n}}+O(1/n) 
$$
with equality sign? Of course, in light of triangle inequality, the above relation with "$=$" replaced by "$\leq$" holds true. Thus, I was wondering whether it is still valid with the equality sign.

Comment: A perhaps useful comment: the function sequence $r_n(t)$ does not need to be bounded in $t$, it only has to satisfy the conditions given in the last bullet point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, it's valid.  To show that the relation also holds with a $\geq$ sign, notice that
$$\int_\Theta f(t) \left| \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} g(x_n) t+ r_n(t) \right|\;dt \geq \int_\Theta f(t) \left| \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} g(x_n) t\right| - f(t) |r_n(t)|\;dt \geq c \frac{|g(x_n)|}{\sqrt{n}}-O(1/n)$$
by the reverse triangle inequality.

---

Notice, however, that if $g(x_n) \to 0$ sufficiently rapidly (i.e. if $g(x) = 0$ and $x_n \to x$ fast enough) then the first term $c\frac{|g(x_n)|}{\sqrt{n}}$ may be asymptotically smaller than the $O(1/n)$ term.  All of the proceeding analysis remains valid, but the asymptotic series you obtain is not as useful in applications as it would be if $g(\lim x_n) \neq 0$.

Comment: Clear. On the other hand, assuming that $\lim_{n \to \infty}g(x_n) =a>0$ and that $h$ is a function with the same properties of $g$ apart from the fact that $\lim_{n \to \infty}h(x_n)=0$, then we can claim that $\int_{\Theta}f(t)\left| \frac{1}{\sqrt{n} } h(x_n) t+ r_n(t)\right|dt$ converges to $0$ faster than $\int_{\Theta}f(t)\left| \frac{1}{\sqrt{n} } g(x_n)t+ r_n(t)\right|dt$, correct?

Comment: Specifically, in the setting of the previous comment, we would have $\int_{\Theta}f(t)\left| \frac{1}{\sqrt{n} } h(x_n) t+ r_n(t)\right|dt=o(1/\sqrt{n})$ while $\int_{\Theta}f(t)\left| \frac{1}{\sqrt{n} } g(x_n)t+ r_n(t)\right|dt=O(1/\sqrt{n})$.

Comment: @JackLondon Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Ok, many thanks.